# Cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects (Basic list indexing)

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a program that asks for the user how many names they have and then prints them depending on the category the fall in (first, middle, and last).

```
names = int(input("Number of names: "))
name_list = []

for i in range(names):
    name_list.append(input("Name: "))

print "First name: " + name_list[0]
print "Middle names: " + name_list[0:len(name_list) - 1]
print "Last name: " + name_list[-1]
```

But I'm getting a TypeError: cannot concatenate `str` and `list` objects on line 9 and I'm not really sure why. I look for the error but I only found way more complex programs and I didn't really get the explanation

Comment: When you slice `name_list` it returns a `list` object, which cannot be concatenated with a `str` object when you are printing.

Comment: there is also an issue with `name_list.append(input("name: "))` at runtime

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is due to the fact you cannot concatenate `str` and `list` objects.

```
name_list=["First_name", "Middle_name1", "Middle_name2", "last_name"]

print "First name: " + name_list[0] # First name: First_name
print "Middle names: " + ' '.join(name_list[1:-1]) # Middle names: Middle_name1 Middle_name2
print "Last name: " + name_list[-1] # Last name: last_name
```